# Will machines on my network be in danger when I port forward a specific port?

Tags: security, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, webserver

The website is running on an Apache2 web server on my Raspberry PI.

Will machines on my network be in danger when I port forward a specific port to make my Apache2 website public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, making machines or services on your internal network available to the world-at-large will always hold some risks.  And in general, [it's a bad idea](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135003/i-want-to-host-a-server-from-my-home-computer-safe).

Start with the issues that @user162397 mentions - You need to make sure to update your Raspberry Pi so that any vulnerabilities in Apache2 (and related components such as TLS/SSL) aren't exploited.  Sound easy?  Remember that newly discovered vulnerabilities can often be widely attacked in a matter of days (and sometimes hours).  I hosted a personal Drupal website at one point that was attacked within a few hours of a patch/update being available.

You also don't mention what type of website you will be hosting, but if it accepts any type of input, then it could be vulnerable to a hack which would allow the hacker to gain access to other features/commands on the Raspberry Pi.  Those features/commands could then be used to access other machines on your network.

The only way it would be remotely safe to do this on a home network would be if your router supported creating a DMZ for the Raspberry Pi that would isolate it from the rest of your network.  And even then, I would recommend that you had above-average networking skills in order to make sure that was sufficient.

Personally, I don't consider a "VPN" solution safe either, since the attack vector can still come in from the VPN.

As @user162397 mentions as well, the best option is to host the website somewhere in the cloud.  You can get an entry-level virtual server (such as Linode or Digital Ocean) for $5/month.  If you really want to "go cheap" and have the desire to learn a bit of AWS, you can even host a static website on S3 (or compatible third-party service) with only the data-storage and data-transfer pricing (usually less than a $1/month, probably more in the range of $0.10 for a personal website).

Answer (score 2):

If you won't install updates regularly then someone could hack your Apache2 and get inside Raspberry PI. From Raspberry PI they could then access your network.

Better put data to some cloud and read it from there, or use router with VPN server so you first connect VPN, then Raspberry.

Stay safe.

Comment: he could set up a firewall maybe.